# Crucible, how to get a list of repos via sql query?

Tags: atlassian-crucible

All,
What table stores repo names in Crucible? I need to build a list of them using sql query.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Repository names are not stored in database, only in config.xml on filesystem.  But there is a REST API call (/rest-service-fecru/admin/repositories) to enumerate them.

(See also answer from developers on https://community.atlassian.com/t5/FishEye-Crucible-questions/Bulk-deleting-400-repositories-in-Fisheye-Crucible/qaq-p/301703)